# Building an object for a cache, "asynchronously" (kind of), in Java: howto?

Tags: java, concurrency

Say you have this kind of code:

```
public final class SomeClass
{
    private final Map<SomeKey, SomeValue> map = new HashMap<SomeKey, SomeValue>();

    // ...

    public SomeValue getFromCache(final SomeKey key)
    {
        SomeKey ret;
        synchronized(map) {
            ret = map.get(key);
            if (ret == null) {
                ret = buildValue(key);
                map.put(key, ret);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

 //etc
 }
```

The problem is performance: if `buildValue()` is an expensive function, then one caller having to build its value will block all other callers, whose value may already exist. I'd like to find a mechanism in which a caller having to build a value will *not* block other callers.

I cannot believe this problem hasn't been tackled (*and* solved) already. I tried to google around for a solution but couldn't find one so far. Do you have a link to do that?

I was thinking about using a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, but couldn't come with anything yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a *very* solid solution to this, based on some work by Doug Lea, who wrote most of `java.util.concurrent`.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava, though I haven't worked on caching at all.)

The user guide article on Guava's `Cache` package is [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained), but the syntax looks like this...

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .maximumSize(1000)
   .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .removalListener(MY_LISTENER)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
         public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
           return createExpensiveGraph(key);
         }
       });
```

Comment: That looks very interesting indeed! I do have Guava as a dependency already, so I'll definitely try that. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Indeed.  Replicating this with `ConcurrentHashMap` is really tricky, just because `putIfAbsent` forces you to have paid the cost of computing the value already, and the alternative is a fancy do-while loop that can still end up with duplicated work.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the issue is that the get method you have appears to be synchronous.  That alone makes it difficult to do anything async.  It seems that your get should take in a callback.

The Java Concurrency in Practice book details an awesome cache using ConcurrentHashMap and FutureTasks - check out http://jcip.net/listings/Memoizer.java

You'll still need to tweak that class to make it asynchronous though - it still blocks the current thread as the task is computed, but it prevents two threads from computing the same thing.  If one thread is already computing it and another wants it, it will wait till the computation is finished rather than starting a new computation

Comment: Excellent~ Add FutureTask, so compute will not happen repeatedly for the same key,quite awesome!

Answer (score 0):

ReentrantReadWriteLock could be a solution: use read lock when you get data from map, while use write lock when you build the data and put it into map. The disadvantage for this solution is: write lock will lock the whole map, so buildValue becomes a synchronized method, when too many caches are write into map, they have to be writen one by one.

Another method is use **java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap**, then you don't need to have any lock by using **putIfAbsent** when you put data into map. The disadvantage is may datas with same key are built concurrently in different Thread, but it won't be a problem unless your appliacation needs strict memory usage.